# Combine windows of the taskbar, but on a per instance basis

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

I've got three instances of an application open.  Each instance has several windows.  When I first opened the second instance, each instance had its own tab.  But at some point when I wasn't paying attention Windows combined all windows of all instances into a single tab.    Now I can no longer tell which window belongs to which instance of the program.  This is problematic for many reasons which I won't go into here.  But suffice it to say that this defeats the whole purpose of having multiple instances running at once.

How can I get windows to properly keep each instance and all its windows in a separate tab?  When I go to "Taskbar and Star Menu Properties" > "Taskbar buttons" it is currently set to "Always combine, hide labels".  If I pick either of the other two options, I am suddenly presented with a separate tab for each *window* which is even less helpful as I now have 13 tabs clogging up the taskbar and I *still* don't know what instance each tab belongs to!

Comment: Use 7+ Taskbar Tweaker to do this. What you want is not native to Windows 10.  https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker

Comment: @John Thanks, I'll take a look at that